# Translate "Rating" as in a rating on a site like on yelp or amazon

Tags: traducción

I'm not sure how I would translate "rating" in reference to a product or service.  What I mean by this is a "rating" that would appear on a site like Amazon or Yelp that aggregated review scores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

> valoración /valoraciones

or

> calificación / calificaciones

or even

> puntuación / puntuaciones

Edit: I just checked and for example ebay.es uses

> Valoraciones más recientes

and

> Valoraciones detalladas como vendedor

Amazon.es uses

> opiniones

But I think that their way of providing feedback and the kind of feedback provided are different, with more verbose comments for Amazon products and with ebay focusing more on seller/buyer grading each other.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In some cases it'll deal more with the context to decide. Sometimes it might sound weird to swap them, but I can't think of a rule off the top of my head. But these are all good options (except opinión and its counterpart reseña probably don't work for purely numerical type stuff)

Comment: @Guifa, great insight. You're right. That's why I edited my post before and gave a couple of real world example of two sites that do different kind of rating for different things. If I could pick only one, based on just the question, I would say "valoraciones", but if we are given more insight about the site or the kind of rating being done we could reach for a term more appropriate and more friendly to Spanish speakers.

Comment: @diego Big help. I was thinking more generally, for building a backend that people can create different types of ratings systems with.

Comment: @guifa yeah I couldn't figure out a great rule either, there doesn't seem to be as general of a word for it.

Comment: @overtime in that case, probably *valoración* or *puntuación* would be best. My instinct is to say that puntuación works better with purely raw numbers, and valoración works better if there's anything qualitative (good/bad, etc) in there too (it will work for numbers as well), but if it's in the backend, anything will be fine, since you'll probably be explaining it to the backend user who could set up custom front-end text or something similar, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

Rating is a common word at least in Argentina, we know what rating means, anyway the translation for this is Puntuación, or Evaluación.

Answer (score 0):

Ratings = Evaluaciones

Decir cuanto vale el producto, por ejemplo, de una a cinco estrellas.

The product is rated 4 stars.

El producto esta' evaluado con quatro estrellas.

Ver EVALUAR, EVALUACION

http://hadoc.azc.uam.mx/evaluacion/queesevaluar.htm

Respuesta firmada por un brasileno con teclado francés ^^